# Wolfram Alpha wrong answers on $(-8)^{1/3}$ and more?

Tags: arithmetic, exponentiation, radicals

Wolfram Alpha doesn't give $-2$ for $(-8)^{1/3}$, and it absolutely fails to draw $f(x)=x^{1/3}$ - does anyone know why? Am I missing something very 'deep' Wolfram Alpha is trying to teach me?

Here's what the graph should look like:
[image]

And here's what Wolfram Alpha draws:
[image]

Comment: Yes. You are missing the fact that cubic root multi-valued (3 values) and W|A gives you the principle value while the other program uses a simpler convention and spits out a non-complex value. Try plotting $x^{1/2}$ instead in both to understand the difference deeper.

Comment: You can get the plot you expect by entering y=Abs(x)^(1/3)*Signum(x) into W/A.

Comment: You can enter `cbrt(x)` for the cube root function in Wolfram|Alpha, which (as implemented in that particular piece of software) is different from $x^{1/3}$.

Answer (score 3):

What you are seeing is that every non-zero number has three distinct "cuberoots". In the first picture you've posted, the software very nicely graphed the real cuberoots. The problem is that Wolfram|Alpha is drawing a different branch of the cuberoot than you are used to, hence the labels of real and imaginary parts on the graph.

Answer (score 1):

The principal value of the cube root is given by *Mathematica* or *Wolfram Alpha*.  If you really just want the real value, input with **Sign[x] Abs[x]^(1/3)**

Answer (score 1):

What you are probably thinking about is that for solving the equation $$z^k = a$$

we often have many solutions (for $z$) in the complex plane. More to the point, for a **function** one wants to **assign one out-value** for each **in-value**. Choosing a particular way to assign function values is called *picking a branch* for a function. For some functions there exist widely used conventions how to pick these branches and they get called **principal** branch. Integer roots and logarithms are famous examples of functions which have a **principal branch**.