# Is ∛ symbol for principal third root or real third root?

Tags: complex-numbers, notation, roots

I thought I knew root notation quite well, but now I am confused, and various sources say different things.

So how much is $\sqrt[3]{-27}$?

[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nth_root#Cube_roots) and [google](https://www.google.cz/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#safe=off&q=-27%5E(1%2F3)) both clearly state that the solution would be $-3$ with this notation. However, it has complex principal root $1.5 + 2.59... * i$, which is the [Wolfram alpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=3rd%20root%20of%20-27)'s solution.

And finally when I pluck it into JavaScript in form of

```
Math.pow(-27, 1/3)
```

it returns NaN, and Python throws math domain error.

What is going on? What does $\sqrt[3]{a}; a < 0$ actually mean? Is it really equivalent to ${a^\frac{1}{3}}$ ? And then there is the analogical question for $$\sqrt[n]{a^n}, a < 0; n\mod2 = 1$$ I am so confused by nth roots now.

Comment: Most of programming languages don't know how to make powers of negative base and float exponent, unless you use explicitly complex numbers.

Comment: In most programming languages 1/3 won't be exactly equal to $\frac13$ so the actual root would be complex.

Comment: Compare the inputs (-27)^(1/3) and cubroot(-27) in Wolfram alpha. It will depend on how their algorithm defines it.

Personally, I would take the $\sqrt[3]{x}$ notation as the positive root.

Comment: Well if you go historically and start with real numbers it denotes the real root. But in complex numbers the usual and more consistent convention is that the $\sqrt[3]{x}$ is actually the principal root (in this case not real). That's why these systems give you this answer. http://mathworld.wolfram.com/CubeRoot.html

Comment: Btw some related questions http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1692727/, http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/25528/.

Comment: Also [related](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2841177/28900).